# Spring @StreamListener: Infinite retries with exponential backoff

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-retry

I'm trying to configure my consumer to work with an exponential backoff where the message will be processed a fixed number of attempts, applying among them the backoff period. But I don't get the expected behaviour.

This is my Java code:

```
@EnableBinding({
        MessagingConfiguration.EventTopic.class
})
public class MessagingConfiguration {

    public interface EventTopic {
        String INPUT = "events-channel";

        @Input(INPUT)
        @Nonnull
        SubscribableChannel input();
    }
}
  
@StreamListener(MessagingConfiguration.EventTopic.INPUT))
void handle(@Nonnull Message<Event> event) {
    throw new RuntimeException("FAILING!");
}
```

If I try the next configuration:

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    events-channel:
      content-type: application/json
      destination: event-develop
      group: group-event-service
      consumer:
        max-attempts: 2
```

After all retries (20*) I get this message:

```
Backoff FixedBackOff{interval=0, currentAttempts=10, maxAttempts=9} exhausted for ConsumerRecord(...
```

2 (`consumer.max-attempts`) * 10 (`FixedBackOff.currentAttempts`) = 20* retries

All these retries occur with 1 second of delay (default backoff period)

If I change the configuration to:

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    events-channel:
      content-type: application/json
      destination: event-develop
      group: group-event-service
      consumer:
        max-attempts: 8
        #Times in milliseconds
        back-off-initial-interval: 1000
        back-off-max-interval: 60000
        back-off-multiplier: 2
```

The backoff period is well applied during the 8 retries (`max-attempts`) BUT when the 8 retries finish a new cycle of retries is started indefinitely blocking the topic.

In the next versions, maybe I will implement a more sophisticated system of error handling but now I only need to discard the message after the retries and get the next one.

What am I doing wrong?

I read a lot of questions/answers here, the official documentation and some tutorials on the internet but I didn't find a solution to avoid the infinite loop of retries.

P.S.: I'm working with `spring-cloud-stream (3.1.1)` and `spring-kafka (2.6.6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the listener container is now configured, by default, with a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with 10 attempts.

This means you are compounding retries.

You can inject a suitably configured `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` using a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` `@Bean`.

It is recommended to not have retries configured in both places; either remove the binding configuration and replace it with a suitably configured error handler, or change the error handler to have no retries.

Comment: Thank you, Gary, you put me in the right way.